# In XUL, how do I make my listbox fill the screen?

Tags: xul

I have the following xul file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="MY TEST" width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <listbox id="mainList">
      <listitem label="Butter Pecan"/>
      <listitem label="Chocolate Chip"/>
      <listitem label="Raspberry Ripple"/>
      <listitem label="Squash Swirl"/>
    </listbox>
</window>
```

..and I would like this listbox to fill the screen (currently it is just on the top).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `flex` attribute

```
<listbox id="mainList" flex="1">
```